# My code throws an error which I thought should be impossible

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
  Public Enum ERight
    ECanInvite = 0
    ECanCreate = 1
    ECanDelete = 2
    etc...
  End Enum


  Public Enum EUserType
    EAdministrator = 0
    EPartner_level1 = 1
    EPartner_level2 = 2
    ENormalUser = 3
    ...etc
  End Enum
```

This below sub, on `rights.add`, sometimes throws this error: `An item with the same key has already been added.`

How is this even possible?

```
Private Shared rights As Dictionary(Of ws_garuda.EUserType, List(Of ERight)) = Nothing

Private Sub initRoles()
    rights = New Dictionary(Of EUserType, List(Of ERight))
    rights.Clear()
    ' Set all rights to false for all roles
    For Each usertype As EUserType In DirectCast([Enum].GetValues(GetType(EUserType)), EUserType())
      rights.Add(usertype, New List(Of ERight))
    Next
End sub
```

Comment: Are you in a multithreaded app (e.g. ASP.NET)?  Is the "rights" field / property that you don't show shared between multiple threads?  Are all your enum values unique?

Comment: @Joe yes, 
the rights are defined as: 
Public Class CRights
  Private Shared rights As Dictionary(Of ws_garuda.EUserType, List(Of ERight)) = Nothing
All enum values are unique

Comment: Please change the title to something that makes sense.  Clearly it is not impossible, because it is happening.

Comment: May be its happen try to add more than one unchanged enum. Better way check before enum is having any changes or else Don't Make Enum as a Key of Dictionary.

Comment: Where is rights declared and where is initRoles called from?

Comment: If I had a pound/dollar for every error my code throws that I thought impossible...

Comment: Can you please post the exception stacktrace? Also please give more details about the type of application.

Comment: @Muleskinner: Create one dummy GUID variable in EUserType. Then Check your code will be work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is happening because you're writing a `Shared` object in a multithreaded environment.

The fix is to add a lock (in which case the call to `Clear()` becomes redundant):

```
Private Shared rights As Dictionary(Of ws_garuda.EUserType, List(Of ERight)) = Nothing
Private Shared rightsLock As Object = New Object()

Private Sub initRoles()
  SyncLock rightsLock
    rights = New Dictionary(Of EUserType, List(Of ERight))
    ' Set all rights to false for all roles
    For Each usertype As EUserType In DirectCast([Enum].GetValues(GetType(EUserType)), EUserType())
      rights.Add(usertype, New List(Of ERight))
    Next
  End SyncLock
End sub
```

Comment: this fix is insufficient, see my answer.

Comment: This fix is sufficient based on the code provided. A lock is also required when reading the Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything stopping your code from calling the initRoles in different places at once?

Since it's a shared variable it's possible one call can get in, clear the variable and then another call can come in, clear the variable and then they both start adding values to the same reference.  Depending how all the blocking is handled internally.

Reminds me of [Dijkstra's Semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) :)  That takes me back.

Anyway may I suggest wrapping this block in something to indicate it is critical code and should be run in one go, each time?  I'm a little rusty in VB but the [SyncLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t%28vs.71%29.aspx) statement would look to be the ticket (code and examples from MSDN in the link).

Answer (score 0):

`initRoles` is an instance method whereas `rights` is a shared/static dictionary.
Shared in a WebApplication means that it's shared across all http-requests because they are different threads. What problably happens it that `initRoles` is called from different requests and all are changing `rights` at the same time.

You haven't shown from where you are calling `initRoles` but i'm sure that it's called from a HttpContext.

If you want the dictionary to be shared, you also should make `initRoles` shared.
You could for example use the shared constructor of class `CRights` to call it:

```
Shared Sub New()
    initRoles()
End Sub

Private Shared Sub initRoles()
    rights = New Dictionary(Of EUserType, List(Of ERight))
    ' blah... '
End sub
```

This approach entails that the dictionary is initialized only once in the application lifetime what might be desired or not. You could also make the method public to enable to re-initialize it f.e. from your User/Role Administration.

Answer (score 0):

The fix suggested by @RickNZ is not enough.  The Dictionary class is not thread-safe, and any synchronization to make its usage thread-safe needs to involve readers as well as writers.  .NET 4.0 has a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) class, and [there exist implementations for .NET 2.0](http://devplanet.com/blogs/brianr/archive/2008/09/26/thread-safe-dictionary-in-net.aspx).

The simplest solution to your immediate problem, which will avoid the need for a thread-safe Dictionary class, is to completely construct the shared dictionary before assigning it to the shared `rights` field.  The easiest way is to change InitRoles into a Shared Function that returns a Dictionary

```
Private Shared rights As Dictionary(Of ws_garuda.EUserType, List(Of ERight)) = InitRoles()

Private Shared Function InitRoles() As Dictionary(Of ws_garuda.EUserType, List(Of ERight))
    Dim tempRights As Dictionary(Of ws_garuda.EUserType, List(Of ERight))
    tempRights = New Dictionary(Of EUserType, List(Of ERight))
    ' Set all rights to false for all roles
    For Each usertype As EUserType In DirectCast([Enum].GetValues(GetType(EUserType)), EUserType())
      tempRights.Add(usertype, New List(Of ERight))
    Next
    InitRoles = tempRights
End Function
```

However, even this will not make your code thread-safe.  Any access to the `List(Of ERight)` values in the dictionary also needs to be synchronized.  And your code implies that this List is not read-only (it is initialized to an empty list, which presumably means it will be modified by code elsewhere in your application).

My advice is to avoid Shared fields for all except immutable objects unless you really understand multi-threading.